# how to compare Json response and UI elements with 2 arrays using for loop in cypress automation

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I have requirement where i need to compare json response data with UI elements . If matching elements found need to print it on log. I need to check all the json response with for loop . Could some one please help me with the code cypress with javascript code. Just to summarise i need a code how to retrieve json data, with java script and cypress. I am pasting sample json below.

from below Json response i need to retrieve the product names and compare with UI product names.

```
"retail": [
    {
      "productId": "6046998e0fce52000138c752",
      "productName": "Dealer Product 2 - Perma ",
      "displayName": "some notes ",
      "coverageOptions": [
        {
          "retailCost": 1017
        }
      ],
      "isTaxable": true,
      "isCapitalized": true,
      "preferenceOrder": "",
      "isTermBased": false,
      "isLessOrEqualMonths": false,
      "providerId": "nontmis",
      "content": {}
    },
    {
      "productId": "610d7f6460fcad0001f6d9a6",
      "productName": "Dealer Product 7",
      "displayName": "This is product seven",
      "coverageOptions": [
        {
          "retailCost": 6000
        }
      ],
      "productTypes": "servicePlan",
      "isTaxable": true,
      "isCapitalized": true,
      "preferenceOrder": "",
      "isTermBased": false,
      "isLessOrEqualMonths": false,
      "providerId": "nontmis",
      "content": {}
    },
    {
      "productId": "610da70960fcad0001f6d9ae",
      "productName": "Dealer Product 8",
      "displayName": "notes....",
      "coverageOptions": [
        {
          "retailCost": 400
        }
      ],
      "productTypes": "other",
      "isTaxable": true,
      "isCapitalized": false,
      "preferenceOrder": "",
      "isTermBased": false,
      "isLessOrEqualMonths": false,
      "providerId": "nontmis",
      "content": {}
    },
    {
      "productId": "610da795489262000147f384",
      "productName": "Dealer Product 9",
      "displayName": "notes...",
      "coverageOptions": [
        {
          "retailCost": 1000
        }
      ],
      "productTypes": "gap",
      "isTaxable": false,
      "isCapitalized": true,
      "preferenceOrder": "",
      "isTermBased": false,
      "isLessOrEqualMonths": false,
      "providerId": "nontmis",
      "content": {}
    },
    {
      "productId": "611d15224d24510001f731f0",
      "productName": "Product Ten",
      "displayName": "This is Product 10",
      "coverageOptions": [
        {
          "retailCost": 400
        }
      ],
      "productTypes": "wearCare",
      "isTaxable": true,
      "isCapitalized": true,
      "preferenceOrder": "",
      "isTermBased": false,
      "isLessOrEqualMonths": false,
      "providerId": "nontmis",
      "content": {}
    },
    {
      "productId": "611d2df0a3e1960001d34c8c",
      "productName": "Credit Disability Test",
      "displayName": "This is the test product for Credit Disability push to routeone",
      "coverageOptions": [
        {
          "retailCost": 1000
        }
      ],
      "isTaxable": false,
      "isCapitalized": false,
      "preferenceOrder": "",
      "isTermBased": false,
      "isLessOrEqualMonths": false,
      "providerId": "nontmis",
      "content": {}
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

So this can done using the `cy.readFile()`

```
cy.readFile("filePath").then((obj) => {
  cy.log(obj); //this prints the entire json file data
  userData.jsonData = obj; //now this variable contains the data
});

//I am assuming that we are verifying "productName" with UI

cy.get("UIDataToBeVerified").each((el) => {
  for (var key in userData.jsonData) {
    let productName = userData.jsonData.retail[`${key}`].productName;
    if (el.text() == productName) {
      cy.log(el.text()); //This prints the product name on UI if it matches
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you Akshaya, i need to check product names from UI and Json should match .. UI has less product names compare to Json .. i need to check if UI Product names are present in JSON then assert it and PASS.. please can you help me assertion also .

Comment: Instead of `cy.log(el.text())` you can use an assertion.
Eg: `expect(el.text()).to.equal(productName)`